# Text border - menu style

Tags: css, styles, border

[image]

Can someone help me to get this kind of line, I have also seen it between categories.

I have tried like this but it is so close, I want it to be between categories.

`#testborder{
border-right: 1px solid grey;
}`

All answers welcome!

Comment: I don't see any the so-called line between categories in your image.

Answer (score 0):

Next time you must give some code before asking. Or you may be not to have an answer

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MM Web Design</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css" />
</head>
<body>
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">bla bla</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">bla bla</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">bla bla</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">bla bla</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">bla bla</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    padding:  0 10px 0 9px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#nav li:first-child {border: none;}
```

Comment: http://www.blockchat.host56.com/send_email.php If you wanted more information, I wanted it to be down in the left corner, you'll understand.